# Entity Framework 4 and Synonyms

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

If, in Database A, there exists a table named "MyTable" that actually comes from a synonym pointing to another database (B), can I create this table as an entity in an Entity Framework model that represents database A, since it actually resides in a different database?

I'm curious if the situation with EF 4 has improved since this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/fff1067a-650d-4b47-a4e8-79eedebe5c11/

Thanks.

Comment: This is not an answer to the above question, but this has been my experience. I had a situation where at a certain stage in the project it was decided to move part of the tables to another database. I did not refresh the mapping of edmx file, but instead I created synonyms and everything worked the way it should.
Because the entity framework does not treat synonyms any different than its parent object, it is also possible to merge the various edmx files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, it is not supported yet; you can track the status of the issue here: http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1052345-support-for-multiple-databases?ref=title

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of your synonym and use a view instead which looks like

```
CREATE view [dbo].[MyTable] as
  select * from B.dbo.MyTable
```

You can then bring this view into Entity Framework and treat it as a table.